# Drag n Drop in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am implementing Drag n Drop functionality in WPF by referring the article

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-enabling-drag-and-drop-on-a-user-control#implementing-drag-source-events-in-the-user-control

I have replaced the Circle control with the textbox and now, I am getting following exception

> **Dispatcher processing has been suspended, but messages are still being processed**

The above exception is coming while initiating the Drag'n'Drop operation. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you will have to do that through dispatcher like example below.

Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox(msg)));